# What causes Fedex integration to report SHIPMENT.USER.UNAUTHORIZED error?

Tags: fedex

I am developing an ERP and Fedex integration program. Yesterday, I could debug it normally through Postman. Today, when I call the interface of Create Open Ship, I get a SHIPMENT.USER.UNAUTHORIZED error. I want to know the reason. It is possible to generate a token using an API key, but when generating a ship, SHIPMENT.USER.UNAUTHORIZED will be reported.

Comment: Hey Ringo, did you find an answer for this? I've hit the same problem today.